# Using an array of subelements on a HTML datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I have some JSON data looking like this:

`{"data":[{"one":"[[1756.53, 2.419583], [13755.95, 0.056274], [1755.62, 0.027065], [11755.59, 0.085065], [1175.28, 906], [11752.33, 0.333531], [11752.31, 0.5], [11752.03, 0.6], [11752.02, 0.107656], [1751.99, 1.288268], ....`

This json is being retrieved through a AJAX request and served to a HTML datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/api/?format=datatables",
        "columns": [
          {
            data: 'one',

          }
        ]
    });
    setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 10000 );
});
```

Where `api` is the api endpoint.

The problem with my actual code is that, when loading the HTML datatable, i will see the data being rendered like this

```
DATA:
[[1848, 84857], [4944, 4949], [34, 65], [3566, 78], .... ]
```

Basically all the JSON gets thrown in a single row of the table.

Instead, i would like to have each record in a single line, like:

```
DATA
1848, 84857
4944 4949 
....
```

After investigating in the network response, i've come to the conclusion that my code sees the JSON response as a string, and not as an array with sub-elements (an array with a series of arrays, each one with two items), hence datatables cannot iterate over it.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using `JSON.parse(yourData)`?

Comment: Yes, but how could it help me in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your main problem is JSON response format. Object data should contains **array of object** or **array of array**. But now seems it was `"json string"` in object `"one"`.

If you can't override your json response from server side, we can altering/relocating data source using Datatables AJAX [DataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option.

> Option of **dataSrc** is to provide the ability to alter what data DataTables
>   will read from the JSON returned from the server, or to manipulate the
>   data from one form into another (be it JSON to another form of JSON,
>   XML, YAML etc).

We need to two (2) part to solve your problem:

1. Relocate JSON data using **[DataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc)** option
2. Convert JSON string as object using using **[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**

code:

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
         "ajax": {
            "type" : "GET",
            "url" : "/endpoint/?format=datatables",
            "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(json.data[0].one));
                return JSON.parse(json.data[0].one);
            }       
            },
       "columns": [
          {"data":0, "title":"col1"},
          {"data":1, "title":"col2"}
        ]
    });
```

**Working demo:**

```js
//This is for JSON request/response mocking only. Do not use this when you have a live JSON server
$.mockjax({
    url: "/endpoint/?format=datatables",
    response: function(settings) {
      this.responseText = {
        "draw": settings.data.draw,
        "recordsTotal": 4,
        "recordsFiltered": 4,
        "data": [
        {"one":"[[1756.53, 2.419583], [13755.95, 0.056274], [1755.62, 0.027065], [11755.59, 0.085065], [1175.28, 906], [11752.33, 0.333531], [11752.31, 0.5], [11752.03, 0.6], [11752.02, 0.107656], [1751.99, 1.288268]]"}
        ]
      }
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
         "ajax": {
            "type" : "GET",
            "url" : "/endpoint/?format=datatables",
            "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(json.data[0].one));
                return JSON.parse(json.data[0].one);
            }       
            },
       "columns": [
          {"data":0, "title":"col1"},
          {"data":1, "title":"col2"}
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mockjax/1.6.2/jquery.mockjax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="mytable" class="display nowrap" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help again. If i try to run the snippet, for some reason it won't retrieve the data from the api endpoint. I tried looking in the developer tools, and there is no request there

Comment: Ok, it was a minor fix to my page. I corrected it and your code is working even better than i expected! Thanks for your help, really!